# Child image(height, width in px dynamically) fit to parent div

Tags: html, css

My issue is that the child image element must fit to the parent div, but the image's height and width are dynamically set.

```css
.people-image-right-parent { height: 150px; width: 150px;background: #EAEAEA; overflow: auto; }
.people-image-right{    width: 220px;
    object-fit: contain;
    height: 220px;
    background: url(http://ndl.mgccw.com/mu3/000/488/937/sss/68ad9b3f576e42399021560560fb3a16_small.png) -491px -235px;}
```

```html
<div class="people-image-right-parent">
    <img class="people-image-right"  />
</div>
```

The image's height and width are dynamic, not fixed, and it should be in pixels (px). I don't want the image to be scrollable or hidden. It must fit to parent element or must be contained in the parent element.

Please guide me on how to fit the image to its parent div.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: people-image-right is id in html but in css you target class

Comment: @jakob i modified my question.

Comment: you set image height width greater than div tag thats why is not proper visible @AkashChavda

Comment: @Bhargav yeah you are right but this is my situation so how child image element fit to parent div element.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```css
.people-image-right-parent {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background: #EAEAEA;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.people-image-right {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(http://ndl.mgccw.com/mu3/000/488/937/sss/68ad9b3f576e42399021560560fb3a16_small.png) -491px -235px;
}
```

```html
<div class="people-image-right-parent">
  <img class="people-image-right" class="" />
</div>
```

Comment: child image element's height width is not in percentage, it should be in pixel. Image height width it's sometimes 50px or sometimes 400px its not fixed.

Comment: so its also working on width height in pixel try it @AkashChavda

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you were looking for?

```css
.people-image-right-parent {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    background: #EAEAEA;
    overflow: hidden; /* If needed you can change this
                      value to "scroll" or "visible". */
}
.people-image-right{
    height: inherit; /* If needed you can change these */
    width: inherit;  /* values to pixel values. */
    object-fit: cover;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="people-image-right-parent">
    <img class="people-image-right" src="http://ndl.mgccw.com/mu3/000/488/937/sss/68ad9b3f576e42399021560560fb3a16_small.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: image have some height width in pixel like it should be 50px or 450px. its not be fixed.

Comment: Then you can change `height` and `width` values to pixel values. As an example: https://jsfiddle.net/0ao4y91g/ However if you use values smaller than `people-image-right-parents`'s you'll end up with some white space.

Comment: I don't want to hidden image. if image height width is 250px then this image fit to parent div but don't hide any pixel

Comment: Then set `overflow`'s value to `scroll` or `visible`.

Comment: I don't want to image in scroll or hidden. I want to image fit to parent div.

Comment: Then set `object-fit` to `cover` and set the `width` to `inherit`, `100%`, or to the same value of the parent div - in this case `150px`. https://jsfiddle.net/ewy2etvn/1/

Comment: please check my question the image tag is not contains src attribute, its in background style with some minus(-) px value

Comment: Then set it back as `background` with these values. I didn't do it because the picture wasn't showing up. (I'm using Firefox.) Hopefully it does work.

Comment: in your updated jsfiddle, image width is inherit but in my case image width is dynamically and it should be in pixel not in percetage

Comment: Check the comment right next to it: `If needed you can change these values to pixel values.` By the way you should update your question to include these criterias.

Comment: yes but when i change it by pixel then image should be hidden some pixel so how can i stop this. I want to fit image to parent div.

Comment: If you want the picture to fit the div and hide what's not fitting use `overflow: hidden`. If not use `overflow: scroll`.

Comment: I dont want to image scroll and hidden just fit to parent div element

Comment: So you want the picture to actually fill the space it's given? Use `object-fit: none` and play with the `height` and `width` values.

Comment: yes like parent width is 150px and child image width is between 100px to 1000px so how image fit to parent div element?

Comment: What do you mean by "image fit to parent div"? If it must fit in height then set its `height` value to the same as the parent div, or to `100%` or `inherit` and fiddle with the `width` property. If it's in width then do all that for the `width` property instead and set the `height` value to your likings.

Comment: image fit to parent div means image have height and width any value is more or less width value from parent div so that image display in parent div properly without hidden and scroll.

Comment: I see. You should then use `object-fit: scale-down` or `object-fit: cover`, with `overflow: none`, and then trick arround with the `height` and `width` values. Also I don't get why you want to change the background image of an HTML tag that doesn't support it. You can't change the background of a space that only exists in its code. I recomend removing the `<img>` tag and keeping its parent div, or completely ignoring the `<img>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if modifying the html is an option but...

You are much better of using an `img` tag inside the parent `div`

In the example below, the images are completely dynamic and will adjust to fit the div no matter what the aspect ratio is. it will also never stretch the image.

```css
.people-image-right-parent {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: darkred;
  line-height: 150px; /* should match your div height */
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0;
}

img.people-image-right {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="people-image-right-parent">
  <img class="people-image-right" src="https://unsplash.it/300/300">
</div>

<div class="people-image-right-parent">
  <img class="people-image-right" src="https://unsplash.it/100/300">
</div>

<div class="people-image-right-parent">
  <img class="people-image-right" src="https://unsplash.it/300/100">
</div>
```

---

**Edit:**

If you can set the height and width of the img inline - even if it's generated dynamically - but cannot control anything else, see the example below. This will work as long as the width and height are declared in px in the img tag whether it's done manually or dynamically.

```css
.people-image-right-parent {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: darkred;
  line-height: 150px; /* should match your div height */
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0;
}
/* demonstration backgrounds */
.bg1 {background: url(https://unsplash.it/500/400);}
.bg2 {background: url(https://unsplash.it/200/600);}
.bg3 {background: url(https://unsplash.it/900/300);}

.people-image-right {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="people-image-right-parent">
  <img class="people-image-right bg1" style="width:300px ;height:300px">
</div>

<div class="people-image-right-parent">
  <img class="people-image-right bg2" style="width:100px ;height:300px">
</div>

<div class="people-image-right-parent">
  <img class="people-image-right bg3" style="width:300px ;height:100px">
</div>
```

Comment: In my case image tag not contain src attribute. image have style and this style contains background property with some minus(-) height width in pixel.

Comment: So you cannot modify the html?

Comment: in my case I am dynamically generate image style and in style i only set width height in pixel value not in percentage value.

Comment: yes i updated your css in my jsfiddle but its hidden image https://jsfiddle.net/523ta69j/3/

Comment: @AkashChavda You should put the background property where you define the background url before the other background properties otherwise they will be overwritten. See this updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/523ta69j/5/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147137/discussion-between-akash-chavda-and-i-haz-kode).

Answer (score 0):

Here try with this

1. If your image is lower(in PX) than your div,you have to use min-width:100% & min-height:100%;
2. If your image is higher(in PX) than your div,you have to use max-width:100% & max-height:100%;

Here is the example, Your image is higher or lower than the parent div it should fit the parent div.

```css
.people-image-right-parent {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    background: #EAEAEA;
    
}
.people-image-right{
    height: 350px;
    width: 345px;
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    min-width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="people-image-right-parent">
    <img class="people-image-right" src="http://ndl.mgccw.com/mu3/000/488/937/sss/68ad9b3f576e42399021560560fb3a16_small.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: If height is more than parent div then not to set 100%. If height is more than parent div then need to set image to parent div without scroll or hidden

Comment: change your height as per your need. Did you try with this. It will works even if your image height is higher than parent div. Snippet updated with image height.

Comment: Even you no need to set width & height for image element. i added only for demo. Image should fix the parent div even width & height for image is low r high.

Comment: can you update in jsfiddle that i defined in my question?

Comment: check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/523ta69j/ see displaying image part. This part i want to fit into parent div without scroll and hidden. ex parent div width is 150px and child image width is 220px.

Comment: Now i update my fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/61rbLpgo/1/ You need to do without change html so this might be help you.

Comment: please check my previous comment. i said in my jsfiddle link displaying image part. See that image part and see your last jsfiddle image part. both are different

Comment: Last one show entire image without losing any portion. Now check this https://jsfiddle.net/61rbLpgo/2/

Comment: i want to display that image part without scroll and hidden not only 150px image part. i want to display 220px image part

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147140/discussion-between-akash-chavda-and-mohamed-mohaideen-ah).